# How to change app developer website information in Apple app store

Tags: ios

How do I change the developer website information for an app?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find out how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok, go to itunesConnect , and change support url field.

Comment: This answer helped me find this on App Store Connect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38612663/841052