# How do I change company website URL is app store app page?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I want to change the website URL for a very old app that I published to IPhone app store. How do I change that URL? I do not want to change the Support URL.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general Apple tech support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Login to iTunes Connect, choose your app and the current version. There you will find both the Support URL and the Marketing URL. I assume you're referring to the Marketing URL as "Company Website URL". You can change them at any time.

[image]